# Three.js: Is throttling / intelligent calling of rendering necessary?

Tags: three.js, rendering, requestanimationframe

Currently I am using a simple loop in Three.js based on `requestAnimationFrame`:

```
...
requestAnimationFrame(animate); // initial call
...

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // do something       

    renderer.render(scene, camera); // always render the scene
}
```

So the `render` function is called each time `animate` is executed via `requestAnimationFrame`. Is that considered good practise? Is the `render`function optimized so that it does not rerender the scene if nothing (visible) has changed? Or do I have to throttle the call / call the function only if something has changed?

Comment: To start, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770521/threejs-stop-rendering/23771782#23771782 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52909816/advice-on-improving-threejs-performance/52915341#52915341